# Capacitance displacement probe guard ring circuitry

Tags: capacitor, ac, sensor, capacitance

I am attempting to build my own capacitance probe for high precision displacement measurements. The working principle is simple - a constant current AC signal (~100kHz) is passed through the probe sensing electrode, and the surface being probed is grounded. As the capacitance between the probe and probed surface changes with distance, the voltage amplitude of the resulting AC signal is directly proportional to the distance.

The circuit for providing the constant current AC signal can be found in [literature](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332363868_Designing_a_High-Precision_AC_Current_Source_to_Measure_the_nm-Scale_Displacements_in_Mechanical_Systems), so for the sake of this post assume that I already have an AC current source. The probe architecture I have decided on is one with a guard ring as shown below.
[image]

From my understanding, the guard ring is held at the same potential as the sensing electrode so it helps ensure the electric field between the sensing electrode and the probed surface is as uniform as possible. My question is how to accomplish this in practice?

Simply connecting the sensing electrode to the guard ring would accomplish this, but it wouldn't work as the edge effects at the guard ring would be included in the measurement, defeating the entire purpose of the guard ring. I am wondering if using an op-amp buffer would work?

Comment: "I am wondering if using an op-amp buffer would work" If it has a low input bias current and a low input capacitance, sure. Other high impedance buffers, like a JFET voltage follower, would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a buffer amplifier (e.g. opamp connected as a unity gain buffer) to drive the guard from the sensing electrode signal. That way the voltage difference between the guard and the sensing electrode will be (ideally) zero; thus that capacitance won't draw any current and so the guard won't affect the sensed signal.

Note that the opamp will (slightly) load the sensing signal -- you will have to calibrate this out of your system.

Note that there are many sources of error in this type of setup that require care and high performance circuits to get accurate and reproducible results.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a buffer amplifier has slightly less than gain of 1; it is
common practice to use a buffer and a boost coil (basically, a transformer) or a modest gain amplifier with a trim (often
a trim capacitor).  Applying a square wave signal, it's easy
to find the best trim adjust point.

Even small dimension variations will change the guard drive
requirement, and if overdriven it causes positive feedback.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your last paragraph? What drives the requirements of the guard drive, other than it being a unity buffer?

Comment: @petemoss0 A guard driven by a buffer sums with other (non-guard) capacitance, so it is beneficial if its gain may be greater than 1, in order to swamp the effect of such stray grounded capacitance.   A guard electrode is a load on the amplifier's output impedance; it might be a FET follower which needs a boost over unity when loaded by the shield.